# How can I apply the data I received from Firebase first?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Given the following code :

```
  Widget Topstocklist(Size size) {

    firestore
        .collection('stock')
        .orderBy("dailynewscount", descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot qs)
    {
      qs.docs.forEach((doc){
        name = (doc['name']);
        perc = (doc['perc']);
        price = (doc['price']);
        newscount = (doc['dailynewscount']);
        print("100");
      });
    }
    );

    return Container(
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      Text(
        '',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
          fontFamily: 'Content',
          fontSize: size.width * 0.025,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          height: 1,
        ),
      ) // Firebase 적용 사항
      ,
      Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Topstock(size, "deci", "+3.2%", 75000, 1200),
              Topstock(size, name, perc, price ,newscount),
            ],
          ))
    ]));
  }
```

```
 Widget Topstock(Size size, String stockname, var stockperc, var stockprice, var newscount) {
    print(stockperc);
}
```

Key point code :
`print("100")`
`print(stockperc)`.

**Expected**

```
I/flutter (15287): 100
I/flutter (15287): //perc = (doc['perc']);
I/flutter (15287): +3.2%
```

**output**

```
 I/flutter (15287): +3.2%
 I/flutter (15287): 
 I/flutter (15287): 100
```

I think this problem relates to the task processing, i.e., asynchronous work, before importing data from the Firebase, but I have not found a solution

How can I get the data from the Firebase and then run the Topstock code?

Comment: Your widget should be a stateful widget where you can call to firebase in the initState lifecycle method. In your build method you can have a boolean flag to determine what to render. This flag should be raised when the data from firebase is received.

Comment: @tomerpacific thanks you but i cant find method